# Evaluate string as an expression

Tags: ruby, math, metaprogramming

How would you convert a string like "2 + 3 + 4" into an expression that ruby will return the value of 9

but as an integer. I was thinking some sort of .each block, but I feel that would be a very long function. If that is the only way, then fine. Just wanted some other eyes on it.

Comment: Someone down votes w/o providing an answer. I have been on goole and stack for the better part of 4 hours searching for a way to do this. I'm just looking for some help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=ruby+execute+string+as+ or https://www.google.com/#q=ruby+expression+string+as+ ... not too hard to find even if you don't know the magic word to include (evaluate)

Comment: This is true, I think I kept using the keyword solve. What if I was not allowed to use eval. what then?

Comment: Thanks. I need to get better with my google-fu . Again. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: that first answer suggests parsing... if you do that, be careful about order of operations and parentheses n such.  whatever you ultimately want, i'm sure someone has already done it in ruby or something similar so take a look around before re-inventing the calculator.  avoiding eval is very understandable but if you *clean your data well* first, the danger of it can be dramatically reduced.

Comment: You said a string "like"... It all depends on what you mean by "like". If it's always integers separated by plus signs, then `str.split('+').reduce(0) { |t,e| t+e.to_i }` is all you need. If "like" permitted any mathematical expression, then it's a toughie, considering that countless mathematicians have devoted their lives so solving just one of the expressions such a method could evaluate.

Comment: Its just +'s and -'s and integers

Comment: What will you be using this for? The accepted answer, to use `eval`, is the simplest thing that works, but it can be dangerous – so whether or not to recommend it would depend on the context of its use.

Comment: That makes sense. And that's the issue that I am dealing with. I have to build my own version now , and sanitize the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)

```
[~]$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > eval("2 + 3 + 4")
 => 9
2.1.2 :002 > eval("2 + 3 + 4").class
 => Fixnum
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just note that `eval` can execute any Ruby code, not just math, so be very careful that you don't evaluate a user-provided string – that could be exploited to steal data, delete files etc.